# Restrict direct access to a custom directory in joomla

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I created a custom folder inside my Joomla root directory. And I want to restrict its direct access. I want to use the subdirectory as Iframe wrapper on the menu or page of my site.
meaning No direct access to
domain.com/form

but i can use it as iframe wrapper in the site

Answer (score 0):

As long as the PHP files have

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
```

at the top, will insure that Joomla is at least loaded.

As for browsing entire directory, that depends on what server using, not a Joomla thing.